# Find all strings containing {A, B, C} with length 3 and don't have AB, BC, or CA as a substring.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

In this case, repetition is allowed, I know there are 12 possibilities because I calculated by hand.
My problem is what formula or combination of formulas I can use to solve this question.

Comment: Are you sure there are only 12 possibilities since repetition is allowed? Because I find 27 possibilities.

Comment: It would be 27 without the exceptions, my question is how to calculate with the exceptions

Comment: What are the exceptions? Because it just says it should be of length three and no substrings of length two and below are allowed.

Comment: That there are no strings containing the substrings AB, BC, or CA

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: If the string contains all of $A,B,C$ and it is of length three there will not be any repetition.  I don't see how you get $12$.  You must have $A$ and you can't have $A$ followed by $A$ or $B$ and you can't have it preceded by $A$ or $C$.  So if it begins with $A$ it must be $ACB$.  If $A$ is in the middle it must be $BAC$ and if $A$ is at the end it must be $CBA$.  Those are the only $3$.

Answer (score 2):

We have to choose three alphabets so for the first letter of the substring, we can choose from 3 letters.
For the second letter in the substring, we have 2 possibilities, since suppose we choose A then we can choose A & C again, and so on.
Similarly, we have 2 possibilities for the 3rd as well.
Therefore, the total number of possible solutions would be $3*2*2 = 12$

Comment: Thank you so much!